# Adding an ImageIcon from inside an object to a frame in another class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
public class Dog {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("dog.jpg");
        image.paintIcon(this,g,200,0);
    }

    public class Gui extends JFrame {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        frame.add(dog.paintComponent(??));
    }
}
```

So the method of paint component from the dog object will be added to a JFrame or JPanel.

IS this the right way of going about it or do you need to call the repaint() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IS this the right way of going about it or do you need to call the repaint() function

Unfortunately, that is not the right way to do it. The `paintComponent(g)` is supposed to be overridden. You will need to extends Dog class to JComponent or one of the JComponent's subclass, then override `paintComponent(g)`:

```
class Dog extends JComponent{
    @Override
    paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //your codes..
    } 
}
```

**However**, if you just want to create a Dog object which can be drawn with custom painting, you do not need to have a `paintComponent()` method. You could simply create a `draw()` method for it:

```
class Dog{

    private ImageIcon image;

    public Dog(){
        java.net.URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource("dog.jpg");
        image= new ImageIcon(imgUrl);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image.getImage(), x, y, width, height, null);
    }

}
```

When you want to draw your **`Dog`** in a canvas or panel:

```
public class DrawingSpace extends JPanel
{
    private Dog dog;

    public DrawingSpace(){
        dog = new Dog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        dog.draw(g);   //will invoke Dog's draw method and draw a dog
    }
}
```

Comment: @thebigone You can take a look at my solution, it is probably what you want.